# doesn't get an embed doesn't come out

Tags: discord.js

I'm going to make a discord.js. When I enter !otherhelp, I try to get an embed, but it doesn't get an embed doesn't come out.

this is my code...

```
const { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const {prefix, token} = require('./config.json')
const fs = require('fs')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
});

const convertEmoji = (who) => {
  if(who === "!가위바위보 가위"){
    return "✌";
  }
  else if(who === "!가위바위보 바위"){
    return "";
  }
  else if(who === "!가위바위보 보"){
    return "✋";
  }
}
client.on('message', msg => {
  if(msg.content === "!서버주소"){
    msg.reply("1.8.9 beargames.mcv.kr");
  }

  if(msg.content === "!가위바위보 가위" || msg.content === "!가위바위보 바위" || msg.content === "!가위바위보 보") {
    const human = msg.content;
    const list = ["!가위바위보 가위", "!가위바위보 바위", "!가위바위보 보"];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    const bot = list[random];
    let winner = "";

    if(human === bot) {
      winner = "비김";
    }
    else {
      human === "!가위바위보 가위" ? (winner = bot === "!가위바위보 바위" ? "봇" : "사람") : "";
      human === "!가위바위보 바위" ? (winner = bot === "!가위바위보 보" ? "봇" : "사람") : "";
      human === "!가위바위보 보" ? (winner = bot === "!가위바위보 가위" ? "봇" : "사람") : "";
    }

    const result =
`
봇 : ${convertEmoji(bot)}
${winner === "비김" ? "우리는 비겼다 인간." : winner + "의 승리다"}
`
    msg.reply(result);
  }

if(msg.convertEmoji === !otherhelp){
  const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor({ name: 'Some name', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .addFields(
      { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
      { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
      { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
      { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'Some footer text here', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png' });

  channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    }
});

client.login('(token)');
```

this is my error

C:\Users\User\Desktop\dev\discordbot\index.js:51
if(msg.convertEmoji === !otherhelp){
^

ReferenceError: otherhelp is not defined
at Client. (C:\Users\User\Desktop\dev\discordbot\index.js:51:26)
at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Desktop\dev\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:33:18)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\dev\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\dev\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:350:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\dev\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\dev\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\dev\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\dev\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1093:20)

Answer (score 0):

`convertEmoji` is not part of the Discord `message` object.

Use `message.content` instead.

```js
if(msg.content === "!otherhelp")
```